# How does this particular struct function like this? (arcsynthesis modern 3D graphics programming)

Tags: c++, struct, syntactic-sugar, aggregate-initialization

I am using arcsynthesis' tutorial to learn modern 3D graphics programming, and while I am understanding most of it I have run into a snag with what the author calls "complex management code" I can't understand how this code works:

```
struct Instance
{
    typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);

    OffsetFunc CalcOffset;

    glm::mat4 ConstructMatrix(float fElapsedTime)
    {
        glm::mat4 theMat(1.0f);

        theMat[3] = glm::vec4(CalcOffset(fElapsedTime), 1.0f);

        return theMat;
    }
};


Instance g_instanceList[] =
{
    {StationaryOffset},
    {OvalOffset},
    {BottomCircleOffset},
};
```

I don't quite get how the function pointer is getting set inside the struct in the g_instanceList[] I don't get syntactically how this works and then how this g_instanceList is used in the next segment here:

```
float fElapsedTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0f;
    for(int iLoop = 0; iLoop < ARRAY_COUNT(g_instanceList); iLoop++)
    {
        Instance &currInst = g_instanceList[iLoop];
        const glm::mat4 &transformMatrix =
currInst.ConstructMatrix(fElapsedTime);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelToCameraMatrixUnif, 1, GL_FALSE,     glm::value_ptr(transformMatrix));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

I thought I was pretty familiar with c++ by this point but this syntactic sugar is new to me.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't quite get how the function pointer is getting set inside the struct in the g_instanceList[]

`Instance` is [an aggregate type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/734069). It may have a member function, but that doesn't make it not an aggregate. In C++98/03, objects of aggregate types can be initialized with aggregate initialization:

```
struct Aggregate
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

Aggregate agg = { 5, 4 };
assert(4 == agg.y); //Will be true.
```

Each member in the struct is initialized with each individual value, in the order in which those members are declared in the struct. The 5 goes into `x` and the 4 goes into `y`.

`Instance` is an aggregate. And it has exactly one member. That member happens to be a function pointer type, but C++ doesn't care; it's a value and it can be used in aggregate initialization.

A C++ array is an aggregate as well. So you can initialize an array with aggregate initialization:

```
int arr[4] = {3, 45, 9, 81};
```

C++ also lets you initialize an array with aggregate initialization, where the size of the array is determined by the initializer:

```
int arr[] = {5, 2};
//arr will have 2 elements.
```

Therefore, `g_instanceList` is an array, and therefore an aggregate which is subject to aggregate initialization. It has a size that will be determined by the number of values provided by the aggregate initialization syntax. Each element of the array is *also* an aggregate, so each element of the array can therefore be aggregate initialized.

```
Instance g_instanceList[] =
{
    {StationaryOffset},
    {OvalOffset},
    {BottomCircleOffset},
};
```

Each member of the aggregate initialization list is itself an aggregate initialization which initializes an `Instance` object. `StationaryOffset` and the rest are function pointers which match the signature of the member of `Instance`. So that's how `Instance::CalcOffset` gets filled in.

---

> how this g_instanceList is used in the next segment here

How it gets used is pretty common C++. The first line gets a reference to one of the `Instance` array elements. This is done just to make the code shorter; it doesn't have to use `g_instanceList[iLoop]` every time to talk about the `Instance` it's using. The second line calls the member function of `Instance` (which itself calls the internal function pointer), storing the result in a variable.

If you're talking about `ARRAY_COUNT`, that's just a convenient macro to get... well, the count of the array elements. The C++ compiler knows how big `g_instanceList` is, so the macro is used to make the compiler compute it itself. That way, if the `g_instanceList` array length changes, you don't have to go through the entire codebase to find every use of the array's length. Also, you never have to directly state the length; you can infer it through aggregate initialization.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I understood ARRAY_COUNT was a macro but the actual code for it has me scratching my head also can you clarify this? #define ARRAY_COUNT( array ) (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))))